# CSS animation only working once

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I start a CSS animation using the following JavaScript code (`element` is a `div`, `name` is the name of an existing rule, `destination` is where the element should move to). The first time this function is called, it works as intended (the `div` moves softly to its final destination). The second time, it simply jumps to the destination (because I explicitly set `left` and `top`), but no movement happens. If I set a breakpoint in the line, where the name assignment happens (`webkitAnimationName`), the animation is performed as it is the first time. Do I need a delay?

```
function flyTo(element, name, destination) {
  var rule = findKeyframesRule(name);
  if (rule != null) {
    element.style.webkitAnimationName = "none";

    // remove the existing 0% and 100% rules
    rule.deleteRule("from");
    rule.deleteRule("to");

    // create new 0% and 100% rules 
    rule.insertRule("from {top: " + element.style.top + ";  left: " + element.style.left + ";}");
    rule.insertRule("to {top: " + px(destination.y) + ";    left: " + px(destination.x) + ";}");

    // assign the animation to our element (which will cause the animation to run)
    element.style.left = px(destination.x);
    element.style.top = px(destination.y);
    element.style.webkitAnimationDuration = "1s";
    element.style.webkitAnimationTimingFunction = "linear";
    element.style.webkitAnimationName = name;
  } else {
    element.style.left = px(destination.x);
    element.style.top = px(destination.y);
  }
}
```

I am using Google Chrome

Comment: Solution found: after setting the animation name, I call a delayed function, which resets the animation name to "none". If the name is cleared and set in one piece of code, the browser doesn't recognize the change and does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the mistake in your code is. But i try to give you another (and in my opinion better solution). Example of my code of a sliding menu:

`#tag-menu {
    top: 0px;
    width: 270px;
    height: 100%;
    left: -370px;
    background: #2F535C;
    z-index: 9;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 0px rgba(84,84,84,0.25);
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    transition: left 0.25s ease-out; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-317px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-317px);
    -o-transform: translateX(-317px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-317px);
}`

`#tag-menu.active{
    left:0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
    -o-transform: translateX(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
    transform:translateX(0px);
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}`

And then u just add and remove the "active" class. The menu will slide. Hope i could help you.
Cheers

Comment: I guess, there will be the same problem: between removing and adding the class, there must be some time, so the browser recognizes the change and starts the animation (or transition). I added a "solution" comment to my question. This way it works with my code.